# How does the VAT algorithm work?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, linear-algebra, similarities, hierarchical-clustering

I want to know how the VAT algorithm for cluster tendency works in detail. As you can see in the picture below, R is the dissimilarity matrix and R-tilda is the ordered dissimilarity matrix. What is the process going from R to R-tilda?

[image]

You can read the full paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3950332_VAT_A_tool_for_visual_assessment_of_cluster_tendency).